# Build array from text file (weird format)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
name
birthday
text
other



name2
birthday2
text2
other2
```

that goes over 10000 lines. 
I want to turn that into a javascript array that looks like this:

```
 [[name,birthday,text,other],[name2,birthday2,text2,other2], ...]
```

There are 4 lines in between each 2 groups (between "other" and "name2"). It would take me hours to do it manually.

The readfile functions I found for javascript while searching all deal with line by line formats and none have group formatting functions like that.

Comment: load it into a string, then split on multiple newlines, then map that array of strings and split by line to get an array of arrays: `str.split(/\n{3,}/).map(x=>x.trim().split(/\n/))`

Comment: @dandavis it worked amazingly well Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the text file and parse it accordingly depending the number of lines you expect per group:

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('test.txt', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    let rows = data.split('\n\n\n\n').map(row => row.split('\n'))
    console.log(rows)
})
```

The first split of `'\n\n\n\n'` is for the 4 lines separation.

This will print:

```
[ ['name', 'birthday', 'text', 'other'], ['name2', 'birthday2', 'text2', 'other2'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

@dandavis 's answer works perfectly.

Load the entire file into one string then do that:

```
var myarray = str.split(/\n{3,}/).map(x=>x.trim().split(/\n/));
```